# Why won't my Javascript popup work anymore?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Afternoon,

I've made a few modifications to the product pages on my website, at some point the popup that confirms a product has been added to the shopping basket has stopped working and I'm unclear as to why...

Original Page:
http://www.dibor.co.uk/Product.asp?ProductId=Y646&title=gentlemenand

New Page:
http://www.dibor.co.uk/Product2.asp?ProductId=Y646&title=gentlemenand

You will see when you click 'add to cart' that on the original page, the popup appears.

I'm stumped and I look forward to hearing from you.

Kind Regards,
Shaun

Comment: Could you please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: Check your commit log and see what's changed.

Comment: Look in the **error console** - `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: use the web console for debug your js.

Comment: @AlexK. I have now updated the issue shown in the log, but still no improvement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery.noConflict()(ready(function() {
  Response.Write("12")
  // Examples - images
  $("#various1").fancybox({
    'titlePosition' : 'inside',
    'transitionIn' : 'none',
    'transitionOut' : 'none'
  });
});
```

Find this in your code. There is an extra ) after this. Remove that

Comment: thanks for the message, I've counted and there are as many open brackets and closed brackets...